# weird extension issue with codefirst EF dataset (inconsistenly returning IEnumerable or IQueryable)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have the following base methods:

```
public IQueryable<T> All
        {
            get
            {
                return Context.DataSet<T>();
            }
        }

public IQueryable<T> Search(Func<T, bool> where)
        {
            return this.All.Where(where); // compiling error, since it returns IEnumerable by default. Why not returning IQueryable?
        }
```

However, when i use the 'All' property in in my service class, it resolves as IQueryable

```
private List<CustomerDomainModel> PrepareBaseResultingData(int id)
        {
            IQueryable<CustomerDomainModel> custs = _customerRepository.All.Where(c => c.ID == id); // it returns IQueryable by default so it is good!
            return custs.ToList();
        }
```

is there any reasons why the "Where clause" extension method returning either IEnumerable or IQuaryable?

**Edited question:**

why does the Search method have compiling error? I would've expected that "this.All.Where(where)" would return IQueryable

Comment: I'm confused. Your property is typed as `IQuerably<All>`... what do you expect from it?

Comment: just updated my code and question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IQueryable.Where<TSource>` method takes an `Expresssion<Func<TSource, bool>>`. Change the `where` argument in your search method to type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and it will compile without a problem.

The reason for your second usage resolving correctly is because of *homoiconicity*.  A lambda expression gets interpreted as either a `Func` or an `Expression<Func>`, depending on the context.  If the method expects the former, the compiler will look at `c => c.ID == id` and see a `Func<int, bool>`; if it expects the latter, it will see an `Expression<Func<int, bool>>`.

Comment: mate you are bloody legend!